# I can't seem to fetch the localstorage string. It shows up in the " localstorage tab " but I just can't retrieve the data, after refresh

Tags: javascript

```
`use strict`;

//assigned all btns to a variable
const addbtn = document.querySelector('.addbtn');
const deletebtn = document.querySelector('.deletebtn');
const clearbtn = document.querySelector('.clearbtn');
const saveList = document.querySelector(`.save`);
var addList = document.createElement('LI');

let listCount = [];

//LOCAL STORAGE
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`saved`));
// alert(localStorage.getItem(`saved`));
localStorage.getItem(`saved`);
//FUNCTIONS

//SAVE
saveList.addEventListener(`click`, function() {
  localStorage.setItem('saved', JSON.stringify(listCount));
  alert(localStorage.getItem(`saved`));
  location.reload();
});

//DELETEALL BUTTON

const deleteAll = function() {
  var ulList = document.getElementById('list');
  var deleteList = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  while (deleteList.length > 0) {
    console.log(ulList.removeChild(deleteList[0]));
  }
};

//EVENTLISTENER

clearbtn.addEventListener('click', deleteAll);

// /// ADDING FUNCTION


addbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const textBoxValue = document.querySelector('.text-box');
  let value = textBoxValue.value;


  if (value === '') {
    alert(`Please add a chore`);
  } else {
    var ulList = document.getElementById('list');
    var addList = document.createElement('LI');
    addList.textContent = value;
    listCount.push(value);

    addList.className = 'list-text';
    ulList.appendChild(addList);
    textBoxValue.value = '';

    //create delete button on list//

    var deleteSingle = document.createElement('button');
    deleteSingle.setAttribute('class', 'btn button');

    //delete clicked list//

    deleteSingle.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Delete'));
    addList.appendChild(deleteSingle).addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.parentNode.remove();
    });
  }
});
```

I have been trying to find the easiest way to just save my todo list so when page is refresh my todos are still there. I tried adding it on the addbtn function but I couldn't get it to work. I thought adding it there so once the add buttong is clicked automatically would save it to the local storage, but I didn't manage to make that work.

So then I created an empty global array and when the addbtn is clicked the input gets added to the array and made a "save" button to save the array into the localstorage and then retrieve it once the page is refresh but I can't get it to work. I see my array list in the localstorage tab but when I refresh the page the list on the actual page is empty. What am I missing? And what is the easiest way to add this into my code?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: When you use `localStorage.getItem()` you don't put the result anywhere.

Comment: You need to put the parsed JSON into `listCount` and then display all of them as todo items.

Comment: could you please write me the code?  you mean this
 < listCount = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`saved`));> inside the save button ?

Comment: Yes, that code will work.  Note that listCount will be null if getItem does not find the key in local storage. So you may want to set a default when the returned value doesn't validate.

Comment: thank you for all the answers but the suggestion on the comment above didnt work.  could someone please post the code for me? I cant seem to think logically while doing this part. its my first time playing around with the localstorage.  thank you in advance :)

Comment: just _look at your code_. you have multiple lines where you show `localStorage.getItem` but you don't do anything with that value. You need to put it in a variable, or pass it to a function, or anything beyond "calling the function and then immediately throwing it away". The alert at least shows you what's in it, but on _that_ note: don't use `alert`, [log to your dev tools console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log). And finally: the `addbtn` code does nothing with localStorage, there is no reason to have it in your post.

Comment: thanks Mike for you help. unfortunately i cant get this to work. idk what im doing wrong :(. i stored  localStorage.getItem into the listCount variable as i was told in the previous message. i guess i just dont really understand the logic behind retriving the data.  i watched tons of videos on youtube and it seems so simple its driving me crazy.